# Finding a particular element in a dynamically generated LinearLayout

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a LinearLayout which contains a number of dynamically generated LinearLayouts based on a class sent to the class that generates the LinearLayout.

The problem is that I have to be able to find an element within the child linear layouts - and as there is nothing to say that the master layout won't be a couple of hundred LinearLayouts in size, has to be quick.

To make things even worse, the layouts are always `TextView` then `EditText` or `Spinner` (never anything else).

Under iOS, this is extremely simple. Android has no Subviews equivalent (it has `ChildrenCount` / `GetChildAt(i)`).

My current solution is to have a `Dictionary<string, List<string,string>>` where the first string is the identifier and the list contains that name of the element (say `editChemical`) followed by "EDITTEXT" or "SPINNER" depending on which it is. The problem is that while this helps, there still doesn't seem to be a way to go through the structure and find the element (here it is `editChemical`).

Is there a piece of magic I can use to find the element in the LinearLayout master tree layout?

Comment: You have a couple **hundred** linear layouts? And then what, you wrap them in a `ScrollView`? That is commonly referred to as a `ListView`. And those have backing models that can be `Dictionary`s if you desire. Each list item can have a type associated with it. Please refer to this tutorial: http://android.leocardz.com/multiple-layout-listview/.

Comment: The problem there is that they're all text views. If that was the case, this would be easy. Here though there is no way of telling if the  next piece in has a TextView and Spinner or TextView and EditView or TextView and TextView. I did consider using a ListView initially. Hmm, me thinks more thought may be involved...